# Add row to table using knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm fairly new to Knockout and JavaScript in general, I am trying to figure out how to get this working I am trying to create a simple shopping list application using knockout.js I have it currently where it's adding the Item Name and quantity to the table however it's adding them both as separate rows instead of row and column.

[HTML Table issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5iih.png)

```js
var SimpleListModel = function(items) {
  self = this;
  self.items = ko.observableArray(items);

  self.itemToAdd = ko.observable("");
  self.quantityToAdd = ko.observable("");

  self.deleteItem = function(item) {
    self.items.remove(item);
    return self.items;
  }

  self.addItem = function() {
    if (self.itemToAdd() != "") {
      self.items.push(self.itemToAdd());
      self.itemToAdd("");
    }
    if (self.quantityToAdd() != "") {
      self.items.push(self.quantityToAdd());
      self.quantityToAdd("");
    }
  }.bind(this);
};

ko.applyBindings(new SimpleListModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<form data-bind="submit: addItem">
  New item:<input data-bind='value: itemToAdd, valueUpdate: "afterkeydown"' /> Quantity:
  <input data-bind='value: quantityToAdd, valueUpdate: "afterkeydown"' />
  <button type="submit" data-bind="enable: itemToAdd().length > 0">Add</button>
</form>
<p></p>
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <th>Item</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Remove</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach:items">
    <tr>
      <td data-bind="text: $data"></td>
      <td><input type="button" data-bind="click:$root.deleteItem" value="X"></input>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

the expected result needs to be:

[Expected result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAt0B.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you're adding the item and the quantity to the items array as separate items. You'll want to use an object instead:

```js
var SimpleListModel = function(items) {
  self = this;
  self.items = ko.observableArray(items);

  self.itemToAdd = ko.observable("");
  self.quantityToAdd = ko.observable("");

  self.deleteItem = function(item) {
    self.items.remove(item);
    return self.items;
  }

  self.addItem = function() {
    if (self.itemToAdd() && self.quantityToAdd()) {
      self.items.push({ item: self.itemToAdd(), quantity: self.quantityToAdd() });
      self.itemToAdd("");
      self.quantityToAdd("");
    }
  };
};

ko.applyBindings(new SimpleListModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<form data-bind="submit: addItem">
  New item:<input data-bind='value: itemToAdd, valueUpdate: "afterkeydown"' /> Quantity:
  <input data-bind='value: quantityToAdd, valueUpdate: "afterkeydown"' />
  <button type="submit" data-bind="enable: itemToAdd().length > 0">Add</button>
</form>
<p></p>
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <th>Item</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Remove</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach:items">
    <tr>
      <td data-bind="text: item"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: quantity"></td>
      <td><input type="button" data-bind="click:$root.deleteItem" value="X"></input>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```